# Akka Typed ActorSelection/Receptionist

Tags: akka

I have question about ActorSelection/Receptionist in new Akka Typed.....

Before Akka Typed I didn't use ActorSelection because I read somewhere that it was not performant so I kept reference to the actor over HashMaps, now I am reading the documentation of the Akka Typed, I see that another mechanism Receptionist exist, so for me the question is, does it also suffers the same problems ActorSelection and I should stick to my old pattern of keeping reference to Actor over HashMap or now the receptionist is the way to go....

My specific scenario, my Actor spawns several Child Actors creates several Child Actors, if the parent Actor passivates or restored over Akka Persistence, it should again find reference to these Child Actors....

So what do you think, would I experience Performance problems if I convert to Receptionist?????

Thx for answers...

Answer (score 0):

`ActorSelection` will resolve the actor path to an `ActorRef` each time you use it, this is somewhat costly, if used for a high throughput actor but has the upside that if the actor is stopped, and then later a new actor is started at the same path, the `ActorSelection` will deliver messages to the new actor, while if you had an `ActorRef` it specifically points to the actor instance that is no stopped and messages end up in dead letters.

The receptionist is quite different and is more like a registry of actors that you can subscribe to. When the set of `ActorRef`s registered for a key changes you get an update message with the new set, there is no extra overhead per message sent, you are dealing directly with the `ActorRef`s of the recipients.

Note that you can use the [`GroupRouter`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/routers.html#group-router) for delivery to actors registered with the receptionist and to avoid having to implement the subscription part in your actor.

Comment: First of all, thx you very much for your answer, of my solution I will nearly have 1000000 instance of same Actor Type (I am using Akka Finite State Machine feature and every actor represents FSM of a Contract, so for Contract1 an Actor Instance will exist and for Contact2 another instance), so I am not so sure it is a good idea to manage this over Receptionist which will deliver a List with 1000000 elements. Even I shard, I will get 300K, 200K Elements in the List... Do you think it is a better to go ActorSelection for this scenario,,,

Comment: I think that will probably be past the upper limit of what works well with the receptionist so you'll probably have to device some other solution. It could be sharding which is much for use cases like this or it could be your own solution where an intermediate actor finds a few other actors on the other nodes through the receptionist and then handles the actual contracts.